# Android Proguard Jackson Problem (No serializer found)

Tags: android, jackson, proguard

I'm having the follow error when I enable the Proguard in my project:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 
No serializer found for class com.myapp.service.MyRequest and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer 
(to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
```

Everything works fine when I disable proguard (minifyEnabled false)

*build.gradle:*

```
   compileSdkVersion 26
   minSdkVersion 19
   targetSdkVersion 26 

   buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

*proguard-rules.pro:*

```
# Jackson
-keep @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties class * { *; }
-keep class com.fasterxml.** { *; }
-keep class org.codehaus.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers public final enum com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility {
    public static final com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility *;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem adding this to *proguard-rules.pro*:

```
-keep public class your.class.** {
    public void set*(***);
    public *** get*();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue. I could solve it by using `keepclasseswithmembers`

```
-keepclasseswithmembers class com.example.ClassName
```

I also had a package where many classes are serialized & deserialized. In this case, I have excluded this package from obfuscation

```
-keep class com.example.package.** { *; }
```